# The specified RegistryOptions value is invalid

Tags: vb.net, registry

What im trying to do is write a key to the registry but im stepping from one problem to another, first permissions problem, now this..
This is the line of code.

```
    If PNGchk.Checked = True Then
        My.Computer.Registry.Users.CreateSubKey(UserSID & "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice", True, Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.FullControl).SetValue("Progid", "SIV.png", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have `Option Strict Off` for that code to even compile, so you might want to fix that to start with.  `Option Strict On` would have flagged issues with that code right away.  You should read the documentation or at least pay attention to Intellisense for that method because your second and third arguments make no sense.  No overload that I can see has a `Boolean` parameter and if you want to use a `RegistryRights` value you do so within a `RegistrySecurity` object as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree worked for me.

```
Using clsid64 = view64.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)

    clsid64.SetValue("StubPath", "SIV.png")
    clsid64.Close()
    End Using
```